Python Unit Tests Stalled in Docker Container when Creating multiprocessing.Manager()
I am running my unit tests in a Docker container, but the below function stalls out when creating the multiprocessing.Manager(). What can I add to my code to get this work? Do I need to make changes to the Docker container?
from multiprocessing import Manager
...
def my_function(self):

   logger.info("Beginning my function.")
   my_manager = Manager()
   logger.info("Manager created.")
   my_manager_list = my_manager.list()
   my_manager_lock = my_manager.Lock()

I am able to run all the unit tests locally, but when I run them in the Docker container (necessary to pass Bitbucket pipeline), the code just stalls until I hit a 2 hour timeout.
Since I'm able to run the unit tests outside the Docker container, I am expecting them to run within the Docker container as well.
